# Как посмотреть сколько ОЗУ занимает процесс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, память

Как с помощью Python посмотреть сколько ОЗУ занимает любой процесс (например `chrome.exe` и т.п.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
import psutil

In [171]: [(proc.name(), proc.memory_info().rss) 
           for proc in psutil.process_iter() 
           if 'firefox' in proc.name().lower()]
Out[171]:
[('firefox.exe', 446230528),
 ('firefox.exe', 93122560),
 ('firefox.exe', 450588672),
 ('firefox.exe', 216768512),
 ('firefox.exe', 546209792),
 ('AppleFirefoxHost.exe', 22958080),
 ('firefox.exe', 371126272),
 ('firefox.exe', 401686528),
 ('firefox.exe', 118554624)]
```

Comment: А еще, вместо `proc.memory_info()[0]` можно `proc.memory_info().rss`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, но у меня остался еще один вопрос: это он выводит в чем значение(байты килобайты и т.п)?

Comment: @gil9red, отличная идея, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexFirsov, это байты...